# Is there a topological interpretation of a module over $\Omega_{PL}(X)$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, rational-homotopy-theory

Associated to a DGCA (differential graded commutative algebra) $A$, we can associate to it the category of modules over $A$. Hence, for a space $X$ we can consider the category of modules over $\Omega_{PL}(X)$, modules over the PL de Rham complex of $X$. The starting point of rational homotopy theory is that $\Omega_{PL}(-)$ is an equivalence upon restricting to simply connected spaces and simply connected DGCA's in a homotopical sense.

I am wondering, perhaps after replacing $\Omega_{PL}(X)$ with a Sullivan model, does this category of modules have a topological interpretation? I am also interested in the d.g. lie algebra analog.

Comment: Given that you want to instead take a modeel, it seems you'd like a topological interpretation of the derived category of $A_{PL}(X)$-modules in terms of $X$?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff This might be the more natural thing to ask for. Do quasiisomorphisms induce equivalences of derived categories?

Comment: Yes, under mild hypothesis (cf. work of Hinich, 1997) quasi-isomorphic dg algebras have equivalent derived categories.

Comment: From a higher-categorical perspective, this equivalence is the stabilization of the equivalence between rational spaces over $X_\mathbb Q$ (which give functors from $X_\mathbb Q$ into spectra) and cdga's over $\Omega_{PL}^\bullet(X)$ (which give the $\infty$-category of modules over $\Omega_{PL}^\bullet(X)$).

Comment: @BertramArnold Do you have a reference for this point of view?

Comment: It seems like maybe [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/rational+parameterized+stable+homotopy+theory) has a somewhat complete account of some references.

Comment: That seems like a reasonable model-categorical approach to this statement. For a more $\infty$-categorical version, one can probably combine the discussion of rational homotopy theory in Heuts' https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.13055 with the discussion of stabilizations in Sections 1.4 and 7.3 of Higher Algebra. One runs into exactly the same issues (algebraic models only work well for nilpotent spaces, coalgebras are harder to handle than algebras since the tensor product does not preserve infinite limits, the dualization between algebras and coalgebras only works well for finite/coherent objects).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TLDR: there is a contravariant adjunction between the derived category of $A_{PL}(BG)$ and the naive category of rational $G$-spectra. In some cases, this is a contravariant equivalence of categories, for example when $G$ is a connected Lie group.

---

If I am not mistaken, the derived category of $A_{PL}(X)$ is equivalent to the homotopy category of modules over the ring spectrum $\operatorname{Map}(\Sigma^\infty X_+, H\mathbb Q)$. I think this follows from a paper of Richter and Shipley.

We may as well pose the question about modules over the singular cochain complex $C^*(X)$, a.k.a modules over $\operatorname{Map}(\Sigma^\infty X_+, H\mathbb Z)$, or even more generally, about modules over the ring spectrum $D(X)=F(\Sigma^\infty X_+, S)$ (the Spanier-Whitehead dual of $X_+$).

When $X$ is a disjoint union, all these rings or ring spectra split as products. So we may assume that $X$ is connected. In this case there is a Koszul duality between cochains on $X$ and chains on $\Omega X$. Or better still, there is a Koszul duality between the ring spectra $D(X)$ and $\Sigma^\infty \Omega X_+$. This implies that there is a contravariant adjunction between the homotopy categories of modules of these spectra. This adjunction restricts to an equivalence between certain subcategories of these module categories. For example, there is an equivalence between finitely generated free cellular modules over either one of the ring spectra, and the so-called nilpotent modules over the other one.

Without loss of generality we may assume that $X=BG$ where $G$ is a topological groups. Then modules over $\Sigma^\infty \Omega BG_+\simeq \Sigma^\infty G_+$ are the same as spectra with an action of $G$. So there is a contravariant adjunction between the category of modules over $D(BG)$ and the naive category of $G$-spectra. Similarly, there is a Koszul duality between the ring spectra $D_{\mathbb Q}(BG)=\operatorname{Map}(\Sigma^\infty BG_+, H\mathbb Q)$ and $H\mathbb Q \wedge G_+$. If I am not mistaken, the homotopy category of modules over $\Omega_{PL}(X)$ is equivalent to modules over $D_{\mathbb Q}(BG)$. So we obtain a contravariant adjunction between this category and the naive category rational $G$-spectra.

This adjunction is not an equivalence in general, but sometimes it is. For example, I think the paper

"[An algebraic model for free rational $G$-spectra for connected compact Lie groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.5575)", by Greenlees and Shipley,

tells you that it is an equivalence when $G$ is a connected compact Lie group. They also give an explicit algebraic model for the category of modules in this case.

I have the feeling that when $G$ is connected and $BG$ is finite, the adjunction is also close to being an equivalence in some sense that can be made precise. Maybe the (naive) category of rational $G$-spectra is equivalent in this case to the category of pro-nilpotent modules over $A_{PL}(BG)$, but I am not 100% sure. There is a paper about derived Koszul duality by Blumberg and Mandell that says something about it.

On the other hand, if $G$ is a finite group, then $D_{\mathbb Q}(BG)\simeq H\mathbb Q$, but the category of rational $G$-spectra of course depends on $G$.

(Incidentally the paper

[Complexes of injective $kG$-modules](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/algebra-and-number-theory/volume-2/issue-1/Complexes-of-injective-kG-modules/10.2140/ant.2008.2.1.full) by Benson and Krause contains some interesting information about the derived category of $C^*(BG; \mathbb F_p)$ for finite $G$.)